# stack around the variable ' ' corrupted in C

Tags: c, stack

i am trying to read names seperated by spaces from a .dat file into an array of structures i have made, however i am getting the error 'Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'player_arr' was corrupted'.
i am new to C so any tips or pointers would be appreciated.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NAME_LEN    31                      /*storage for single name*/
#define TEAMSIZE    14                      /*creates teamsize 0-14 (15 total)*/

void readNames();

typedef struct{
    char name[NAME_LEN];                    /*bowlers name ie 'jones'*/
    int oversLatest;                        /*bowlers overs, latest and overall*/
    int maidensLatest;                      /*bowlers maidens, latest and overall*/
    int runsLatest;                         /*bowlers runs, latest and overall*/
    int wicketsLatest;                      /*bowlers wickets, latest and overall*/
    int strikeRate;                         /*bowlers strike rate*/
    double average;                         /*average */
} player_t;

FILE *input;

int i, count;
char c;


int main(void)
{
    readNames();

    return 0;
}


/* function to read input2a.dat and assign the name to the player_t structure
*/
void readNames(){
    input = fopen("input2a.dat", "r");      /**/

    player_t player_arr[TEAMSIZE];
    count = 0;

    do{
        c = fscanf(input, "%s", &player_arr[count].name);
        printf_s("%s\n", player_arr[count].name);
        count++;
    } while (c != EOF);
    fclose(input);
}
```

Comment: Start by breaking out of your loop once `count` reaches `TEAMSIZE`. Also `c` should be `int`, ahd you should be checking the result of the `fscanf` before going on to do `printf` and `count++`. To improve your code, make `c` and `count` be local variables inside `readNames`.

Comment: To prevent a `fscanf` overflow, change `"%s"` to `"%30s"`. Consider using `fgets` instead.

Comment: You don't need the & before player_arr[count].name.  Array variables are also pointers.  Also, make sure that none of the names are more than 31 characters.  Basically, you are corrupting the physical stack memory above or below the player_arr, variable, probably by reading in names that are too long.  EDIT:  Matt McNabb has the reason why you are probably corrupting the stack...  Too many loops!

Comment: Are all the names one one line or is it playername followed by that player's stats all on the same line? On top of everything else mentioned I noticed you are using Win32 and you are already using some of the secure functions namely `printf_s` . Using them makes your code less portable but if you do use them then I recommend also using `fopen_s` and `sscanf_s` along with `fgets`. Depending on your compiler options it may already warning you about the unsafe versions.

Comment: breaking the loop did it, thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Corrupting memory.

The following allocates memory for 14 teams, but the comment implies your have 15 teams in the file.

```
// #define TEAMSIZE    14    /*creates teamsize 0-14 (15 total)*/
#define TEAMSIZE    15    /*creates teamsize 0-14 (15 total)*/
player_t player_arr[TEAMSIZE];
```

`while` may loop too far.  Wrong type for `scanf()` return value.  Too late checking if `scanf()` return value is good.  @Matt McNabb
Info on [printf_s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/239ffwa0.aspx)

```
// char c;
int c;
while ((count < TEAMSIZE) && 
    ((ch = fscanf(input, "%30s", &player_arr[count].name)) == 1)) {
  printf_s("%s\n", player_arr[count].name);
  count++;
}
```

Insure you are not reading too long a name.  No need for `&` in front of arrays. @c.fogelklou

```
#define NAME_LEN    31                      /*storage for single name*/
char name[NAME_LEN]; 
// c = fscanf(input, "%s", &player_arr[count].name);
c = fscanf(input, "%30s", player_arr[count].name);
```

Did not check if file opening succeeded.

```
input = fopen("input2a.dat", "r");
if (input == NULL) Handle_Failure();
```

Best to read file's line into a buffer with `fgets()` and then parse that buffer with `scanf()`, `strtok()`, etc.